# How do you comment on a specific answer?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I mean, comment on a comment? How do I do that?

Comment: I was also wondering how I can comment on a question. Well, now that I found out that I just cannot do it with 1 rep, will this increase my rep..? ;)

Answer (score 9):

You need 50 rep to comment globally, unless it's either …

1. your question
2. an answer to your question

… in which case you can comment with 1 rep.

Meta has a different ruleset from the other trilogy sites and allows global commenting with 1 rep. All rep levels are documented on the /faq page as usual.

(shamelessly stolen from mmeyers' comment, but he should have left it as an answer!)

Comment: There is no shame when it comes to rep-whoring.

Comment: I vote that Jeff must re-allocate a portion of his rep points to those that have made bug and feature suggestions that actually get accepted as a reward :) Then again, when TheTXI has more rep then the site owner....

Comment: He's right **on** the pony's tail. There's no way he'd give up rep now.

Answer (score 4):

You have to have 50 reputation before you can leave a comment on stackoverflow, but you only need 1 on meta.

Comment: true with caveats; see my answer

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you mean : To comment not on a question or answer, but on one of theirs comments.

---

What I've seen, and am doing also, is to **prefix my answer with `@author`**, where `author` is the name of the person who wrote the comment.

Comment: This only works for comments, not answers apparently.