# What does @user mean?

Tags: support, comments, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the relevance of “ @ “ in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21866/what-is-the-relevance-of-in-comments)

I often see `@user` here and there in the comments.

What, pray tell, does it mean and what is it used for?

Comment: Like the previous question?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25725

Comment: Oh, I missed that question. Now I feel slightly silly for answering this one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean *@username: ...* as used in comments? That is just to signal who the comment is for, especially if this is not the original poster.

Comment: @Stephan202 COOL!!!

Comment: @Luis: VERY!!!!

Comment: But, of course, it is broken, because users can freely change their display name...not that I let that stop me from using it.

Comment: You need it because comments move up as they are voted so it's not obvious that you are replying to the immediately preceding poster