# how do I comment?

Tags: support, comments, new-users, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Answer or comment: what's the etiquette?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette)

I have just started using stack overflow. I have a rep of 26, How do I comment? I cannot see any link or input box to comment. (I noted that a rep of 1+ is needed)

Comment: Dup of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette ?

Comment: @Benny, No that question is about whether to comment versus answer.    This is more like a dupe of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25725/148310

Comment: @Brock Adams, Im sorry. I did have a thourough search first.

Comment: no problémo.  But, I shan't be surprised if people close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need a rep of 50 to comment.
See https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation-abilities

Right now, you can only comment on your own questions, or your own answers.

Comment: ah yes, it seems I was looking at the "meta stack overflow" FAQS

Comment: The FAQ says different though. It says "† you can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you’ve asked, even with 1 rep." So either you or the FAQ is mistaken... (Funny as it is though, i seem to be able to comment here...)

Comment: @poepje, You can comment here because, alas, the required rep is lower on meta than on SO.  Also, notice that the **question** was about SO and commenting on other people's questions.  Finally, how does my answer disagree with the FAQ?  It doesn't.

Comment: you said it yourself, the FAQ is about SO and not this. So with my 13 rep on SO I should be able to use the function. Besides, I wouldn't even have found this site if I didn't click the FAQ link on SO. Wasn't it you who gave the link to that same paragraph in the same FAQ concerning commenting on SO?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is confusing for the new user. I've been there myself. It's confusing because you see other people's comments but you don't see any links to add comments.

I think that maybe a link to "comment" should appear regardless of the reputation, but then check the reputation score when user clicks the link and show small message "you need reputation score of at least 50 to add comments"

What do you guys think?